# Node identifiers in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j - just started playing with it yesterday evening.

I've notice all nodes are identified by an auto-incremented integer that is generated during node creation - is this always the case?

My dataset has natural string keys so I'd like to avoid having to map between the Neo4j assigned ids and my own. Is it possible to use string identifiers instead?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Think of the node-id as an implementation detail (like the rowid of relational databases, can be used to identify nodes but should not be relied on to be never reused).

You would add your natural keys as properties to the node and then index your nodes with the natural key (or enable auto-indexing for them).

E..g in the Java API:

```java
Index<Node> idIndex = db.index().forNodes("identifiers");

Node n = db.createNode();
n.setProperty("id", "my-natural-key");
idIndex.add(n, "id",n.getProperty("id"));

// later
Node n = idIndex.get("id","my-natural-key").getSingle(); // node or null
```

With auto-indexer you would enable auto-indexing for your "id" field.

```java
// via configuration 
GraphDatabaseService db = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("path/to/db",
 MapUtils.stringMap( 
    Config.NODE_KEYS_INDEXABLE, "id", Config.NODE_AUTO_INDEXING, "true" ));

// programmatic (not persistent)
db.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().startAutoIndexingProperty( "id" );

// Nodes with property "id" will be automatically indexed at tx-commit
Node n = db.createNode();
n.setProperty("id", "my-natural-key");

// Usage
ReadableIndex<Node> autoIndex = db.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().getAutoIndex();
Node n = autoIndex.get("id","my-natural-key").getSingle();
```

See: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/auto-indexing.html
And: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing.html

Comment: Thanks Michael, exactly what I needed to know. This stuff is obviously not too mainstream yet, documentation and discussion is very light on the ground!

Comment: @Michael Hunger when you call n.setProperty("id","my-natural-key"); you are creating a different id from the auto-generated node ide that neo4j creates correct? Or is this an attempt to overwrite the id that neo4j is using?

Comment: @michael-hunger Is it possible to add a auto-increment property? Or do I have to create unique ids for nodes I create?

Comment: Another important point to notice is that when you provide your own id, make sure its value isn't very large. Better is to stick with incremental nature. Otherwise, on db close, Neo4j engine takes considerable time to shutdown, moreover, the size of db on disk is also very large.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

> Create the index to back automatic indexing during batch import  We
>   know that if auto indexing is enabled in neo4j.properties, each node
>   that is created will be added to an index named node_auto_index. Now,
>   here’s the cool bit. If we add the original manual index (at the time
>   of batch import) and name it as node_auto_index and enable auto
>   indexing in neo4j, then the batch-inserted nodes will appear as if
>   auto-indexed. And from there on each time you create a node, the node
>   will get indexed as well.**

Source : [Identifying nodes with Custom Keys](http://neo4j.com/blog/batchinsert-auto-indexing-and-friend-recommendation-with-neo4j/)

Answer (score 0):

According Neo docs there should be automatic indexes in place 
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html
but there's still a lot of limitations

Answer (score 0):

Beyond all answers still neo4j creates its own ids to work faster and serve better. Please make sure internal system does not conflict between ids then it will create nodes with same properties and shows in the system as empty nodes.

Answer (score 0):

the ID's generated are default and cant be modified by users. user can use your string identifiers as a property for that node.