# neo4j auto-increment multiple queries

Tags: neo4j

I'm quite new to neo4j. I'm developing a web app(using express.js and async) that does a POST request, which in turn creates a triangle of nodes and relationships. So, there are 6 queries and I want to use auto-increment ID (or rowID) of the created nodes (using id(a)) to create relationships.

As I saw in another post([Node identifiers in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051442/node-identifiers-in-neo4j?rq=1)), rowID should not be relied for reuse. But, I have no other way of identifying my nodes (unless if I create an index on all the properties which is a pain).

Hence, my question, can I use rowID for this use-case ? If not, what kind of use case suits better for rowID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need an id to create the triangles, then you can use id(n), but probably you can just create the triangle with a single cypher statement.

Perhaps you can share more of your code/domain?

Usually you should have a business-key / -id that you can use.

Comment: That's what I ended up using, but now my code looks more procedural than object-oriented. I can live with it for now till I figure out a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own id and store it on the node as a property, if you have no unique id that you can use.

Comment: I guess if I followed this approach, I'd have to maintain the nextID for use, storing it in a file if my server crashes. Doable, but not elegant, I think.

Comment: Or use a uuid or similar where you don't need to know the previous.