# Changing neo4j's embedded id field

Tags: mysql, laravel, neo4j

Is there a way to change the default ID field attached to every label from auto-incremented integer to MySQL's equivalent big integer with unique index?

I have researched the manual and saw a question here but didn't get this answered. I will be migrating a big db to neo4j and don't want to make an additional property to store any id fields from the source RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

i was wondering about the id field too and i found this thread related to it:
[Node identifiers in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051442/node-identifiers-in-neo4j)

more or less it say : do not rely onto the auto generated idfield.

Comment: that is the thread I found too but nothing concrete can be derived from it as I am trying to change it not use it as is.