# How to find a subset of nodes and return their id's in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to write a cypher query which allows you to pass in a set of names as strings to find matching nodes and then return each node's id.  I've been playing around with the language and came up with the following flawed query:

```
START person=node(*)
WHERE HAS (person.name)
WITH FILTER (name IN ['ryan','mike'] : person.name=name) AS matchedPersons
RETURN ID(matchedPersons)

Expected `matchedPersons` to be a node or relationship, but it was ``
```

If I return `matchedPersons` instead of `ID(matchedPersons)`, I get this result:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| matchedPersons                           |
+------------------------------------------+
| ["ryan"] |
| ["mike"] |
| []                                       |
+------------------------------------------+
3 rows
```

In my database, I have three person nodes that have the names 'ryan', 'mike', and 'lucy'.  I want to get the ID's of the people that match the names in the collection defined in the FILTER clause.  How can I get the ID's of each person who has a name that matches at least one of the names in the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much simpler way to write this query:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$  match (p:Person) where p.name in ['ryan', 'mike'] return id(p);
+-------+
| id(p) |
+-------+
| 14680 |
| 14681 |
+-------+
2 rows
96 ms
```

(Tested on some local data, so your IDs will be different).

OK, so that's how to do it.  But here's the thing - you probably shouldn't look at, deal with, or care about the IDs of individual nodes.   [See this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051442/node-identifiers-in-neo4j).  Node IDs should be thought of as an implementation detail.  All they'll ever do for you is provide a unique identifier, but you should make zero assumptions about what their value will be.   Don't make assumptions like that they'll never change, or that they're always ordered in a certain way.  If you need an identifier with actual meaning, use your own.

Comment: Interesting read, however I am getting the ID's to build a relationship using the Neo4JTemplate class.  The create relationship method in that class calls for node id's.

Comment: Not familiar with that class or what you're trying to do there.  All I can suggest is that if there's an alternate method that deals with a `Node` object instead of IDs, that would probably be preferable so that you can let someone else worry about the details of IDs.  I try not to mess with them because 9 times out of 10 they're not what you want.  You might have an exception though because of how you're using them, I'm not sure.

Comment: these are the id's of the node, you can use the `template.query()` method with this query replacing the collection with a named parameter and returning p, then you have your nodes
`template.query("match (p:Person) where p.name in {names} return p",map("names", asList("ryan","mike"))).to(Node.class);`

Comment: Hey @FrobberOfBits would you mind dropping me an email at michael@neo4j.org ?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I sent you an email.